# Does Class URLDecoder.decode handle double encoding?

Tags: java, urldecode

I am trying to debug a flaky Java application. I can't (easily) debug it in the only way I would know how - by putting a log statement in it and re-compiling. Then checking the logs.

(I don't have access to a reliable set of source code). And I'm not a Java developer.

The actual question:

If I did this:

```
str = URLDecoder.decode("%25C3%2596");
```

What would be in str?

Would it realize that this is double-encoded and handle that i.e. turn it into %C3%96 - and then decode that? (Which decodes into a German Umlaut).

Thanks

--Justin Wyllie

Answer (score 0):

From the Java API [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html):

**A sequence of the form "%xy" will be treated as representing a byte where xy is the two-digit hexadecimal representation of the 8 bits.**

So my guess would be - most likely not.

You could however call the `decode` method twice.

```
str = URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.decode("%25C3%2596"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = URLDecoder.decode("%25C3%2596");
```

The result of this operation is system-dependent (the reason the method is deprecated.)

The result of [this call](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
str = URLDecoder.decode("%25C3%2596", "UTF-8");
```

...would be `%C3%96` which is Ö in percent-encoded UTF-8. The API does not try to recursively decode any percent-signs.